# What is formula minimum speed (in term of $r,d,g$) needed to fly over sphere object that has radius r and at distance d?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

(I am not expert in English. I will write as well as I can.)

The is a challenged physics question.
(Originally, this question have a picture but I doesn't have it. It is very old question that I only know its concept. I draw pictures in this post.)
To understand the question easier, let see picture.

[image]

From this picture, what is minimum initial speed to throw red ball over this sphere?

(assume red ball is very small and throw form h=0)

d and R can be any positive real number which d>r.

If you think the movement path of red ball likes this

[image]

you are wrong. Why? Let see this picture.

[image]

The maximum point of the movement path isn't necessary to be at the top of sphere.

Morever, in this case,

[image]

The movement path is different from previous case.

Because of this, I don't know how to use a condition of this sphere to solve this problem.

I think about it many time but still don't know, please help me.

Comment: Do not re-post closed question. Especially do no try to hide the fact that you are re-posting closed questions.

Comment: Did you restore that questions-400725?

Comment: Did you notice it because it doesn't seem like question? If this is true, okay, I know you can't check all question and all thing that it use to be every time. No matter!, next time, I think you won't notice again. (I may create new account.)